# Why List<double> type is behaving in this way?

Tags: c#, list

This a small program to add,remove, insert into items(double) into Ilist collection .

```
 class ProgramL
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList<double> myList = new List<double>();
            myList.Add(1.54);
            myList.Add(56.54);
            myList.Insert(1,58.54);
            myList.Add(11.44);
            myList.Add(121.44);
            myList.Add(111.44);
            myList.Add(1221.44);
            myList.Add(1331.44);
            myList.Add(161.44);
            myList.Add(21.58);
            myList.Remove(21.58);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

So there are exactly 9 items left after the add,insert and remove operations.
But according to the picture why the list contains 16 items. The last 7 items are initialised to 0.0 values.

[image]

Can any one please explain this to me ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking on internal array? Yes, it bigger then size of list, so you does not have to resize it on every call to `Add`.

Comment: What you are seeing is the capacity of list which List internally handles. Your screen shot shows the variable `_size` with value of 9. That is actual size of list.

Answer (score 5):

There are two numbers:

- `Count` - actual number of elements added to the list
- `Capacity` - size of array used to store elements under the hood

It's to improve performance and reduce number of allocations for the underlying array the `List<T>` is using to store elements.

When you instantiate the list and add first element it's created with initial capacity (4 elements). When you add elements and existing capacity is not enough, underlying array will be reallocated to contain twice as many elements. That's because reallocating the array is quite expensive, and you don't want it to happen every single time you add element to the list.

You can use `TrimExcess` method to make underlying array size be closer to the number of items in the collection.

> This method can be used to minimize a collection's memory overhead if no new elements will be added to the collection. The cost of reallocating and copying a large `List<T>` can be considerable, however, so the `TrimExcess` method does nothing if the list is at more than 90 percent of capacity. This avoids incurring a large reallocation cost for a relatively small gain.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because List is implemented as a Java-like Arraylist, where a backing array is used to store the elements. If the backing array is filled up, the list makes a new, bigger backing array and copies the elements. This takes some time, which is why (to increase performance) the backing array's size is increased in certain steps and may therefore be bigger than the actual count of the elements in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, `List<>` stores the values in an array. That array starts off with 4 elements and, when full, expands to 8, then 16 etc. Because you have allocated 9 elements to the list, the array is 16 elements long.

The list keeps track of the number of elements of the array used via `Count`. `Capacity` holds the size of the array.